# File "_none_", line 1: Error: Required module '<>' is unavailable

Tags: makefile, ocaml

The make file has been executed, there is no bug reporting from each file. However, in terminal, I received:

```
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Required module `Prettyprint' is unavailable
```

The `Prettyprint.ml` is one of my files. What does this error report mean? Thank you for your help.

First edit:
My makefile looks like:

```
@echo "# Lexer & Parser:"
ocamlc -g -c parser.mli lexer.ml parser.ml
@echo "# mainfile"
ocamlc -g -c TransitionalSemantics.ml
ocamlc -g -o main str.cma AbstractSyntax.cmo 
TransitionalSemantics.cmo Prettyprint.cmo StaticSemantics.cmo 
lexer.cmo parser.cmo
```

In my terminal, the error report begins at:

```
ocamlc -g -o main str.cma AbstractSyntax.cmo 
TransitionalSemantics.cmo Prettyprint.cmo StaticSemantics.cmo 
lexer.cmo parser.cmo
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Required module `Prettyprint' is unavailable
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object files must be linked in an order compatible with their dependency digraph: if one of your module depends on the `Prettyprint` module, it must be linked after `prettyprint.cmo`.

Starting with 4.13, the error message is more informative and looks like

```
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Wrong link order: B depends on A, B depends on A
```

Answer (score 3):

You should show exactly what you did to get this error. Otherwise we have to guess :-)

The `File "_none_"` part means that you're typing in the toplevel so there's no file per se.

The `Error` part means that the toplevel can't locate your module named `Prettyprint`. Possibly you need to load it before you do whatever else you did:

```
# #load "prettyprint.cmo"
```

(The first `#` here is the toplevel prompt. The second one is something you should actually type.)

If you expand your question to include more details you will possibly get a more helpful answer.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply and guidance. Yes, I will enhance my question. Indeed, I have learned from your answer as how to promote to toplevel.